# how to unit test a function that returns livedata

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

In my viewModel, I have a function that returns liveData. This function is directly called in the fragment and hence it is observed directly there. I am not able to get how can I test this function since liveData emitted by the function is not getting observed in case of tests and hence it will not return the value.

This is my function, I want to write test for:

```
    fun saveRating(rating: Float, eventName: String): LiveData<Response<SaveRatingData?>?> {
        val request = RatingRequest(rating.toDouble(), eventName, false)

        return liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(repository.saveRatings(request))
        }

    }
```

and this is how I am calling it in a fragment:

```
   viewModel.saveRating(rating, npsEventData?.eventName ?: "").observe(this, Observer {
      // on getting data
   })
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a testCoroutineDispatcher or testCoroutineScope to be able to set scope of your viewModel to scope of testing.

```
class TestCoroutineRule : TestRule {

    private val testCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    val testCoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope(testCoroutineDispatcher)

    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description?) = object : Statement() {

        @Throws(Throwable::class)
        override fun evaluate() {

            Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)

            base.evaluate()

            Dispatchers.resetMain()
            try {
                testCoroutineScope.cleanupTestCoroutines()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    fun runBlockingTest(block: suspend TestCoroutineScope.() -> Unit) =
        testCoroutineScope.runBlockingTest { block() }

}
```

Try-catch block is not mentioned in any official kotlin or Android documents but testing exceptions cause exceptions instead of passing the test as i asked in this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61730593/coroutines-test-exception-is-not-handled-with-neither-testcoroutinedispatcher-no).

And another thing i experienced with testCoroutineDispatcher as dispatcher is not enough for some test to pass, you need to inject coroutineScope instead of dispatcher to viewModel.

For instance

```
fun throwExceptionInAScope(coroutineContext: CoroutineContext) {


    viewModelScope.launch(coroutineContext) {

        delay(2000)
        throw RuntimeException("Exception Occurred")
    }
}
```

You have a function like this that throws exception and you pass testCoroutineContext to this test it fails.

```
@Test(expected = RuntimeException::class)
fun `Test function that throws exception`() =
    testCoroutineDispatcher.runBlockingTest {

        //  Using testCoroutineDispatcher causes this test to FAIL
        viewModel.throwExceptionInAScope(testCoroutineDispatcher.coroutineContext)

        //  This one passes since we use context of current coroutineScope
        viewModel.throwExceptionInAScope(this.coroutineContext)

    }
```

It passes if you use class `MyViewModel(private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope)`

Now, let's get to how to test liveData with asynchronous tasks. I use this class, Google's `LiveDataTestUtil` class, for synching `liveData` and

```
@get:Rule
var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

as rule

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.getOrAwaitValue(
    time: Long = 2,
    timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS,
    afterObserve: () -> Unit = {}
): T {
    var data: T? = null
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    val observer = object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
            data = o
            latch.countDown()
            this@getOrAwaitValue.removeObserver(this)
        }
    }
    this.observeForever(observer)

    afterObserve.invoke()

    // Don't wait indefinitely if the LiveData is not set.
    if (!latch.await(time, timeUnit)) {
        this.removeObserver(observer)
        throw TimeoutException("LiveData value was never set.")
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return data as T
}

/**
 * Observes a [LiveData] until the `block` is done executing.
 */
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeForTesting(block: () -> Unit) {
    val observer = Observer<T> { }
    try {
        observeForever(observer)
        block()
    } finally {
        removeObserver(observer)
    }
}
```

Now, you can test it same as you test synchronous code

```
@Test
fun `Given repo saves response, it should return the correct one` = testCoroutineScope.runBlockingTest {

        // GIVEN
        val repository = mockk<<Repository>()
        val actual = Response(...)
        coEvery { repository.saveRatings } returns actual

        // WHEN
        val expected = viewModel.saveResponse()

        // THEN
        Truth.assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected)

    }
```

I used mockK, which works well with suspending mocking.

Also you don't need to use `Dispatchers.IO` if you have retrofit or Room function calls, they use their own thread with suspend modifier if you are not doing other task than retrofit or room actions.

Comment: Thanks @Thracian! It helped but, I had to add instantTaskExecutorRule too. Without it, it was given the NullPointerException on the liveData.

Comment: You are welcome, i also wrote about above LiveDataTestUtils but it's not set to display as code so you might have missed it. I change it now to code.